# What Subject only emits items after subscribing

Tags: rx-java2

In rxJava, I want a subject to only start emitting "new" items after the subscribe method is called. The closest I found to this is PublishSubject but the docs state the following:

> PublishSubject emits to an observer only those items that are emitted
>   by the source Observable(s) subsequent to the time of the
>   subscription.
>
> Note that a PublishSubject may begin emitting items immediately upon
>   creation (unless you have taken steps to prevent this), and so there
>   is a risk that one or more items may be lost between the time the
>   Subject is created and the observer subscribes to it.

It isn't exactly clear what is meant by "unless you have taken steps to prevent this". Or is there a better subject type I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [publish](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/publish.html) operator:

> it does not begin emitting items when it is subscribed to, but only when the Connect operator is applied to it. In this way you can prompt an Observable to begin emitting items at a time of your choosing.